# How to get overall duplicate count?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have below mentioned dataframe:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "
Date         ID
2018-04-01   K-1
2018-04-01   K-1
2018-04-01   K-8
2018-04-02   K-2
2018-04-02   K-2
2018-04-03   K-2
2018-04-03   K-2
2018-04-03   K-2
2018-04-04   K-3
2018-05-01   K-5
2018-05-01   K-5
2018-05-02   K-6
2018-05-02   K-7", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

By using above mentioned datafram i want to determine below mentioned metric:

```
Date       Unique_count      Duplicate_Count      Overall_Duplicate
2018-04-01 2                 1                    0
2018-04-02 1                 1                    0
2018-04-03 0                 0                    3
2018-04-04 1                 0                    0
2018-05-01 1                 1                    0
2018-05-02 2                 0                    0
```

Where:

- `Unique_count`- Distinct `ID` created for a particular date the `ID` should not be match with any previous `ID`.
- `Duplicate_count` - count of additional (if there are 2 `K-1` than - `Duplicate_count` should be 1) same `ID` generated for a particular date, the same `ID` should not match with any previous `ID`.
- `Overall_Duplicate` - count of `ID` that has previously generated and again present on the particular date.

I have below mentioned code, not sure about `Overall_Duplicate`:

```
library(dplyr)

DF2 <- DF %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Unique_Count  = n_distinct(ID),
            Duplicate_Count = sum(table(ID)>1))
```

Comment: @zx8754 group by with date right??

Comment: Sorry, still trying to understand your output, why row 3 "Unique_count" is 0?

Comment: @zx8754 Because ID `K-2` was previously generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first group by ID and find the first time each ID appears, you can then change all the subsequent IDs (after the first time they appeared) to NA and then do some calculations to get what you want.

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(first_time = min(Date)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(ID = ifelse(Date == first_time, ID, NA)) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(Unique_Count = n_distinct(ID, na.rm = TRUE),
            Overall_Duplicate = sum(is.na(ID)),
            Duplicate_Count = n() - Unique_Count - Overall_Duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this. But it's hardcoded according to your reproducible data. In real life there could be false positives.

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>%
  mutate(id=duplicated(ID)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(OLdate=n_distinct(Date)>1) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(Unique_count=sum(!na_if(id, T), na.rm = T),
            Duplicate_Count=ifelse(Unique_count == 0, 0, sum(id)),
            Overall_Duplicate=ifelse(Unique_count == 0,sum(OLdate), 0)) 
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Date       Unique_count Duplicate_Count Overall_Duplicate
  <chr>             <int>           <dbl>             <dbl>
1 2018-04-01            2               1                 0
2 2018-04-02            1               1                 0
3 2018-04-03            0               0                 3
4 2018-04-04            1               0                 0
5 2018-05-01            1               1                 0
6 2018-05-02            2               0                 0
```